# Android decrease size of graphic in application

Tags: android, size, screen-resolution, reduce, graphic

I use bitmaps in application and work with .bmp or .png formats. I try to comply with standards from developer android page  - [Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

But if I use bitmaps on background and also on imageviews and imagebuttons my application is very huge. Let's say about 40 MB. What is the best way to make graphic the smallest size ?

Of course I can use some tools such as PngCrush to decrease size but it helps only little bit.
I was looking on other applications they are full of graphics and it has only for example 12 MB. How does they reach so small size of application ? Because I don't know using openGL, using images is one and only way to use at the moment. What is the difference in data size when using OpenGL in comparision with using images ? Do you think if I have a lot of graphics I must start with OpenGl using ?

Do you have any interesting tips to make the smallest graphic ?

Comment: 40Mb sounds like a lot of different images. Are you sure no images are duplicated ? some densities are rare and can be ignored (default image will be used in this case). Also, why is the size of the app of some concern ?

Comment: I make experiment with images in drawable-hdpi. Other densities I ignore at the moment. My friends working on Android say 40 MB is unusual a lot of data and i should decrease it, this is why I am looking to decrease size of app.

Comment: if you have gradients, square borders ... you can replace them by xml files.

Comment: Thanks for tip on gradients and borders. This can surely help I will try to implement.

Comment: more generally, check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html . There are various types of drawable that can be used, you can combine some, add some padding to others ... in order to reuse those that are alike as much as possible.